# Convert using Latin1 equivalent in Redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

We are trying to model the same logic used in mysql to redshift.
There is a `convert(md5() using latin1)` script in mysql which I am unable to find the equivalent redshift script for.

Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode it to UTF-8 (or any Redshift supported format) from latin1 before using MD5() on it. 

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: I cannot change the mysql script which kind of puts me in a difficult situation